# Combining two select statement into single output

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to build a query that joins two SELECT statements into one single output.

I am using Amazon Redshift.

I have attached the query I have built as below:

```
with q1 as (
    select count(invoices) as count,to_char(billtime,'yyyy-mm-dd'), store 
    from sales
    group by to_char(billtime,'yyyy-mm-dd'), store
),
q2 as (
    select count(a.invoices) as count1, b.store,
        to_char(a.billtime,'yyyy-mm-dd')
    from sales_detail a, dim_store b
    where a.store_id = b.id
    group by b.store, to_char(a.billtime,'yyyy-mm-dd')
)
select q1.count(invoices), q2.count(a.invoices), q1.store
from q1
left join q2
    on q1.store = q2.store
group by q1.store;
```

I am getting an error that says invalid operation  column does not exist unnamed join.

Could anyone assist. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select statement seems to be the problem.  As you have already aliased the counts in each of the two CTEs, you may just select those aliases:

```
SELECT
    q1.store, q1.count, q2.count1
FROM q1
LEFT join q2
    ON q1.store = q2.store
GROUP BY q1.store;
```

As far as further improvements go, since you ultimately want a store level aggregation from both tables, there is no need to aggregate by billing date *and* store in each CTE.  So, for the first CTE you could have just used this:

```
WITH q1 AS (
    SELECT store, COUNT(invoices) AS count
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY store
)
```

But perhaps you pulled the CTEs from somewhere else where you do need the double aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION instead of CTE, and be careful that both queries have the same column names. After that transponse columns and rows.